# Multiprocessing process.start() in a notebook does nothing?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, multiprocess

I have 5 separate functions I want to execute in parallel:

```
# Defining the BO acquisition function
acquisition_function = UtilityFunction(kind="ei",xi=1e-1)

# Defining a wrapper function that calls maximize - wilson
def wilson_wrapper():
    print('in wilson wrapper')
    wilson_optimizer.maximize(
        n_iter=n_iter_BO,
        init_points=init_points_BO,
        acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )

# Defining a wrapper function that calls maximize - wong
def wong_wrapper():
    print('in wong wrapper')
    wong_optimizer.maximize(
        n_iter=n_iter_BO,
        init_points=init_points_BO,
        acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )

# Defining a wrapper function that calls maximize - jansen
def jansen_wrapper():
    print('in jansen wrapper')
    jansen_optimizer.maximize(
    n_iter=n_iter_BO,
    init_points=init_points_BO,
    acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )

# Defining a wrapper function that calls maximize - larter
def larter_wrapper():
    print('in larter wrapper')
    larter_optimizer.maximize(
    n_iter=n_iter_BO,
    init_points=init_points_BO,
    acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )

# Defining a wrapper function that calls maximize - kuramoto
def kuramoto_wrapper():
    print('in kuramoto wrapper')
    kuramoto_optimizer.maximize(
    n_iter=n_iter_BO,
    init_points=init_points_BO,
    acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )
```

in a jupyter notebook. For some reason, when I try to define each as a process in this way:

```
from multiprocess import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wilson_process = Process(target=wilson_wrapper)
    wong_process = Process(target=wong_wrapper)
    jansen_process = Process(target=jansen_wrapper)
    larter_process = Process(target=larter_wrapper)
    kuramoto_process = Process(target=kuramoto_wrapper)

    wilson_process.start()
    wong_process.start()
    jansen_process.start()
    larter_process.start()
    kuramoto_process.start()

    wilson_process.join()
    wong_process.join()
    jansen_process.join()
    larter_process.join()
    kuramoto_process.join()
```

Nothing happens, with or without `if __name__ == '__main__'` (cell just runs in 0.3 seconds, and no `print()` statements print). I tried defining it in a different way, where I make one function and a list of all the `optimizer` objects that will be called:

```
def main_wrapper(optimizer, n_iter_BO, init_points_BO, acquisition_function):
    print(optimizer)
    optimizer.maximize(
        n_iter=n_iter_BO,
        init_points=init_points_BO,
        acquisition_function=acquisition_function
    )

optimizers_list = [wilson_optimizer, wong_optimizer, jansen_optimizer, larter_optimizer, kuramoto_optimizer]
```

then with:

```
from multiprocess import Process

max_pool = 5    
with Pool(max_pool) as p:
    pool_outputs = list(
        tqdm(
            p.imap(partial(main_wrapper, n_iter_BO, init_points_BO, acquisition_function),
                optimizers_list),
            total=len(optimizers_list)
        )
    )

# Getting the results of the 5 repetitions from the process outputs
multiprocessing_outputs = list(zip(*pool_outputs))
multiprocessing_outputs = list(multiprocessing_outputs[1])
print(multiprocessing_outputs)
```

And this also doesn't work. Is there any way to run 5 independent functions in a Jupyter Notebook? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Try placing your worker functions (e.g. `wilson_wrapper`) in an external file from which you import them rather than in a Jupyter Workbook cell.

Comment: Hello, the cell runs now, thank you so much!! I'm not getting any output from the functions (now in their own Python file) in Jupyter though - is this expected? :)

Comment: When you start Jupyter Notebook a console window is opened in addition to a browser window (at least on Windows that is the case). Do you see your output in the console window? That is where you would have seen error messages before you moved your worker functions to an external file.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure which you're talking about! I'm running the notebook from VSCode, so I dont really see the console window. Now I'm running on Colab. Is there anything I should see?

Comment: I am not familiar with those environments.